# Multiple conditions within WHERE clause

Tags: sql, mysql, jdbc

This query is working fine:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename where Date >'20091109' and id='11';
```

But below this query does not return anything.

```
SELECT * FROM tablename 
WHERE Date BETWEEN ('20091109' AND '20081010') AND id='11';
```

Comment: You need to put the 20081010 _before_ the 20091109.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
between ('20091109' and '20081010')
```

This is anything after 9th Nov 2008 and before 10th Oct 2008. Of course if show nothing.

Do you mean this which is 10 Oct 2008 to 8th Nov 2009 *inclusive*

```
Date >= '20081010' AND Date < '20091109'
```

or this which is 10 Oct 2008 to 9th Nov 2009 *inclusive*

```
Date >= '20081010' AND Date < '20091110'
```

Edit: Removed SQL Server references

Answer (score 2):

```
   SELECT * FROM 
   tablename 
   where Date between '20081010' and '20091109' 
   and id='11';
```